# Bootstrap-confirmation delete photo

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

This is the first time i use bootstrap-confirmation. I am trying to delete photo's when they press delete then the confirmation wil popup. If they click on OK we can delete the photo. My problem is that when i have 3 photo's and 3 delete buttons and you click on the third button he will remove the first image. Here is my code:

```
$(function(){
        var removeFunction = function(id) {
            var number = id.split('_');
            var foto = $('#foto_' + number[1]).attr('href');
            var p_id = $('#hidden_field').data('p_id');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "verwijderfoto",
                data: {foto: foto, p_id: p_id},
                cache: false,
                success: function () {
                    $('#delete_' + number[1]).hide();
                    $('#load').fadeOut();
                    $('#foto_' + number[1]).hide();
                    $('.text_delete_' + number[1]).append("Geen foto");
                }
            });
        };
        var clickedDeleteButton = $('[data-      toggle=confirmation]').confirmation({
            title: "Weet u het zeker ?",
            btnOkLabel: "Ok",
            btnCancelLabel: "Cancel",
            btnOkId: "test",
            onConfirm : function() {
                $('body').trigger('confirmed.bs.confirmation');
            }
        }).click(function(){return $(this).attr('id')});
        $('body').on('confirmed.bs.confirmation', function()   {removeFunction(clickedDeleteButton.attr('id'));return true});
        return false;

    });
```

If i return $(this) in clickedDeleteButton i will get the right id but i think because i trigger the body to soon he wont get the right id.

This is the html code:

```
 <a href="<?php echo $data['fotoproduct']->foto1?>" class="delete" id="foto_1" data-lightbox="Image-1"><img class="lightbox-foto" src="<?php echo $data['fotoproduct']->foto1 ?>"></a>

 <button class="btn btn-default btn-danger" data-foto="<?php $data['fotoproduct']->foto1 ?>" id="delete_1" data-placement="top" data-toggle="confirmation">X</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on the [Bootstrap Confirmation](http://mistic100.github.io/Bootstrap-Confirmation/) documentation , it says

> Confirmation tries to cancel the default event of the target and trigger it when the "Ok" button is clicked. However, in order to have the good behavior, the plugin must be initialized before manually attaching event listener (with `$.on()`).
>
> If this is not possible, you could listen the `confirmed.bs.confirmation` or use the `onConfirm` callback.

so I just refined your js a bit

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="confirmation"]').confirmation({
        title: "Weet u het zeker ?",
        btnOkLabel: "Ok",
        btnCancelLabel: "Cancel",
        btnOkId: "test"
    });

    $('#imgs > button').on('click', function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('id').split('_');
        removeFunction(id[1]);
    });
});

function removeFunction(id) {
    var href = $('#foto_' + id).attr('href');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "verwijderfoto",
        data: {
            foto: href,
            p_id: id
        },
        cache: false,
        success: function () {
            $('#delete_' + number[1]).hide();
            $('#load').fadeOut();
            $('#foto_' + number[1]).hide();
            $('.text_delete_' + number[1]).append("Geen foto");
        }
    });
};
```

[ALSO CHECK THIS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nprL2pc3/)

Comment: Thanks for replying ! When i use your code and click on the danger button it already removes the photo without confirmation. How can i fix this ?